# I want to download MS teams recorded video by another person

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to download the videos recorded by another person from MS Teams, The course is going on and due to my slow internet connectivity, I can'y stream recorded video. SO i want to download it but there isn't any option to download the video

Comment: That is a question for the person responsible for the video.

Comment: You should use https://github.com/snobu/destreamer

Comment: @John if you use destreamer you don't have to ask the person who recorded the video to enable downloading.